# Align images and text with GridView

Tags: android, gridview, textview, imageview

I have the following [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqspt.jpg).

As you can see, the week days text and the "column title" images are not aligned to the GridView items.

Here is the complete xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="11"
tools:context="com.test.me.fragments.patientResume">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/aboveLights"
        android:src="@mipmap/above_lights"
        android:contentDescription="@string/above_lights" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/under_lights"
        android:contentDescription="@string/under_lights" />


    <com.test.dashboard.view.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/centerImg"
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_default_avatar" />
    <com.test.dashboard.view.widget.RobotoLightTextView
        android:id="@+id/PatientName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/aboveLights"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/aboveLights"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/aboveLights"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/aboveLights"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity = "center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Mauricio Affonso"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp">

        <com.test.dashboard.view.widget.RobotoLightTextView
            android:id="@+id/took_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/took"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <com.test.dashboard.view.widget.RobotoLightTextView
            android:id="@+id/took_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/took_header"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="-"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <com.test.dashboard.view.widget.RobotoLightTextView
            android:id="@+id/missed_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/missed"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <com.test.dashboard.view.widget.RobotoLightTextView
            android:id="@+id/missed_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/missed_header"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/missed_header"
            android:layout_below="@+id/missed_header"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.test.me.wave.WavesView
        android:id="@+id/waves_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="#ddf7ff">

    <com.test.dashboard.view.widget.RobotoLightTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/countPatient"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="1 OF 1"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleImages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/backgroundLight">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/morning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="30dp"
            android:maxHeight="30dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_morning" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/noon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="30dp"
            android:maxHeight="30dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_noon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/evening"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="30dp"
            android:maxHeight="30dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_evening" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bedtime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="30dp"
            android:maxHeight="30dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_bedtime" />
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:id="@+id/tableContainer"
    android:background="@color/backgroundLight">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/date_layout"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />

    <com.test.me.grid.DateLayout
        android:id="@+id/date_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/Sun"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:text="SUN" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Mon"
        android:text="MON" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Tue"
        android:text="TUE" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Wed"
        android:text="WED" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Thu"
        android:text="THU" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Fri"
        android:text="FRI" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Sat"
        android:text="SAT" />


</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see the content of RelativeLayout titleImages and the week days text should be aligned to the GridView items but i'm having different results on different phone resolutions. I even tried to dynamically change the positions:

```
int test[] = new int[2];
int space = grid.getHorizontalSpacing();
int height = grid.getMeasuredHeight() / 7;
int Width = grid.getColumnWidth() / 2;
int paddingTop = grid.getPaddingTop();
int paddingLeft = grid.getPaddingLeft();

Resources r = getResources();
float spacePx = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, space + 10, r.getDisplayMetrics()) ;
float paddingTopPx = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, paddingTop - 7, r.getDisplayMetrics());
float paddingLeftPx = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, paddingLeft - 12, r.getDisplayMetrics());
grid.getLocationInWindow(test);

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    Days[i].setY(paddingTopPx + (test[1] - grid.getMeasuredHeight()) + ((i +1)* (height)));
}

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    icons[i].setX((paddingLeftPx + test[0]) + (i) * (spacePx + Width));
}
```

Comment: I better suggest use a different layout use dimens for fixed size of view in as phones and tablets

Comment: I am working on that but couldn't make completely as your need as i dont have time

Comment: If you can just show me the path to make this happen is already a great help!

Comment: I tried using layout change but its all waste best way to achieve your need is by using 1 single gridview and add smtwtfs as its first column item

Comment: Thanks, i'll do that.

Comment: Answer not perfect if couldn't work please comment down will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with different layout but all seems not that perfect so the best way to make your view is use single gridview .Almost succeded but you have to work on that more logic to get exactly what you need

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_calender"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />
```

day_view

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_new"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/text_height_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/text_height_width"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Create adapter with a better logic as needed its an edited code,Please **ignore the commented codes Thanks**

```
 public class CustomCalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    static final int FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 0;
    public ArrayList<Day> dayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] days;
    Context context;
    List<Boolean> event_status;
    // Calendar local_cal_30 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
    Calendar cal;

    public CustomCalendarAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Day> dayList, List<Boolean> _event_status, Calendar cal) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dayList = dayList;
        this.event_status = _event_status;
        this.cal = cal;
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        refreshDays();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return days.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

//  public int getPrevMonth(){
//      if(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH)){
//          cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR-1));
//      }else{
//
//      }
//      int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
//      if(month == 0){
//          return month = 11;
//      }
//
//      return month-1;
//  }

    public int getMonth() {
        return cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (position % 5 == 0) {
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.day_view, null);
            TextView day = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_new);
            if (position / 5 == 0) {
                day.setText(R.string.sunday);
            } else if (position / 5 == 1) {
                day.setText(R.string.monday);
            } else if (position / 5 == 2) {
                day.setText(R.string.tuesday);
            } else if (position / 5 == 3) {
                day.setText(R.string.wednesday);
            } else if (position / 5 == 4) {
                day.setText(R.string.thursday);
            } else if (position / 5 == 5) {
                day.setText(R.string.friday);
            } else if (position / 5 == 6) {
                day.setText(R.string.saturday);
            }
        } else {


            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
            Day dayObject = dayList.get(position);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.day_view, null);
//            RelativeLayout rl_outerView = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rl);

//            FrameLayout today = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.today_frame);
//            FrameLayout event = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.event_frame);
//            FrameLayout disable_frame = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.disable_frame);
//            FrameLayout selected_frame = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.selected_frame);
            TextView tv_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_new);
            Calendar local_cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
            tv_date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            rl_outerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            selected_frame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (dayObject.getDay() == 0) {
//                rl_outerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                tv_date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tv_date.setText(String.valueOf(dayObject.getDay()));//sets the date
            }


            //Only show 30 days from current date
//         if ((dayObject.getDay()<local_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) &&
//               dayObject.getMonth() == local_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) || ((dayObject.getMonth() == local_cal_30.get(Calendar.MONTH))&&
//               dayObject.getDay()>local_cal_30.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))) {

            //Only show upcoming dates from current date
            if ((dayObject.getDay() < local_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) &&
                    dayObject.getMonth() == local_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))) {
                //These dates come out of 30 days(Based on current date)
//                disable_frame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                //Rest days come here
//                disable_frame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dayObject.setDisable_date(true);
//                event.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tv_date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


                //Now compare the schedule date list with each date for matches
                for (int i = 0; i < CustomGridCalendarView.schedule_list.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        Date scheduleDate = format.parse(CustomGridCalendarView.schedule_list.get(i).getScheduleDate());
                        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.setTime(scheduleDate);
                        if (dayObject.getDay() == cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) &&
                                dayObject.getMonth() == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) &&
                                dayObject.getYear() == cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                                ) {
                            //Show the event frame, here we got a match date
//                            event.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                            today.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            tv_date.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        }
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (dayObject.isEvent_status()) {
//                    event.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                    selected_frame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    today.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                } else {
//                    selected_frame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                }

                //Check for current date
                if (dayObject.getYear() == local_cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) && dayObject.getMonth() == local_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                        && dayObject.getDay() == local_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
//                    today.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    tv_date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//                    event.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                    tv_date.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                } else {
//                    today.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    public void refreshDays() {
        boolean before_current_date = true;
        // clear items
        dayList.clear();

        int lastDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 7;
        int firstDay = (int) cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        //TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();

        // figure size of the array
        if (firstDay == 0) {
            days = new String[lastDay + (FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK * 6)];
        } else {
            days = new String[lastDay + firstDay - (FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK + 1)];
        }

        int j = FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK;

        // populate empty days before first real day
        if (firstDay > 0) {
            for (j = 0; j < (firstDay - FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK) + 7; j++) {
                days[j] = "";
                Day d = new Day(0, 0, 0, false);
                dayList.add(d);
            }
        } else {
            for (j = 0; j < (FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK * 6) + 7; j++) {
                days[j] = "";
                Day d = new Day(0, 0, 0, false);
                dayList.add(d);
            }
            j = FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK * 6 + 1; // sunday => 1, monday => 7
        }

        // populate days
        int dayNumber = 1;

        if (j > 0 && dayList.size() > 0 && j != 1) {
            dayList.remove(j - 1);
        }

        for (int x = 0, i = j - 1; i < days.length; i++) {
            Day day;
            if (event_status.size() > x) {
                day = new Day(dayNumber, year, month, event_status.get(x));
            } else {
                day = new Day(dayNumber, year, month, false);
            }


            x++;
            Calendar cTemp = Calendar.getInstance();
            cTemp.set(year, month, dayNumber);
            //int startDay = Time.getJulianDay(cTemp.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(tz.getOffset(cTemp.getTimeInMillis())));
            days[i] = "" + dayNumber;
            dayNumber++;
            dayList.add(day);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you meet your need ?

Comment: yes, i made some changes to fit my app, but now its perfect. Thanks!